# template function different result depends on reference type

Tags: c++, c++11

I am making a simple structure that holds two iterators and I can use range based for loop.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <class TIterator>
struct Range
{
 Range(const TIterator &begin, const TIterator &end)
     :_begin(begin), _end(end) {}

 TIterator begin() { return _begin; }
 TIterator end() { return _end; }

private:
 TIterator _begin;
 TIterator _end;
};

template <class TRange>
auto make_range(TRange r) -> Range<decltype(std::begin(r))>
{
    return { std::begin(r), std::end(r) };   
}

template <class TRange>
auto make_range2(TRange &r) -> Range<decltype(std::begin(r))>
{
    return { std::begin(r), std::end(r) };   
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5};
    auto r = make_range(vec);

    for (auto i : r)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;   // 0 0 3 4 5 or 0 2 3 4 5 depends on compiler
    }

    std::vector<int> vec2 = {1,2,3,4,5};
    auto r2 = make_range2(vec2);

    for (auto i : r2)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;   // 1 2 3 4 5
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The first loop print out `0 0 3 4 5` or `0 2 3 4 5` (unexpected) and second loop print `1 2 3 4 5` (as expected)

Can someone explain to me why `make_range` does not give correct value? and how can it produce `0 0 3 4 5` or `0 2 3 4 5`? Do I used any undefined behaviour, or this is compiler bug?

live examples: [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a80ea48ecd829874) and [Ideone](http://ideone.com/YOAV8a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make_range` takes its parameter by value. `r` is a temporary which is destroyed when the function returns, invalidating all iterators into it. The subsequent attempt to dereference said iterators exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In make_range(TRange r), r is a local copy of the vector, which goes out of scope, invalidating the iterators.